# Redefine domain class mapping at runtime

Tags: grails, dynamic, groovy, mapping

I was wondering if there is a way in groovy to change the `static mapping` section of a grails class at runtime. As of now my domain class looks like this:

```
class Result {

    ObjectId id

    String url

    def Result(){

    }

    void addObjectProperty(String key, value){
        this[key]=value
    }

    //No constrains defined yet.
    static constraints = {
    }

    static mapWith="mongo"

    static mapping = {
        collection "results"
        database "test"
    }
}
```

Now lets just say I want to change the mapping section at runtime to:

```
static mapping = {
    collection "xyz"
    database "mydb"
}
```

Now when I call `save()` on an object it saves the result to mydb in the collection xyz. I bet there is a way in groovy to accomplish just that but since I'm new to groovy I'm having a hard time here ... it would be nice if someone could point me into the right direction.

Thanks a lot...

Comment: Even if this is possible, I wouldn't do it. Seems like a world of hurt just waiting to happen.

Comment: So what would you suggest to do?

Comment: That would depend on the reason for needing to remap.  I've never ran into a situation where I needed the mapping changed that didn't effect all data in a more permanent way.

Comment: I'm with Gregg. I'd probably define a domain class hierarchy, with one child class for each mapping configuration that you need, and choose the domain class to instantiate and save based on whatever runtime check you were planning on doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note my comment above about the wisdom of doing this. That said, you can replace your mappings at runtime with Groovy's metaclassing functionality.

```
Result.metaClass.'static'.mapping = {
    collection "myCollection"
    database "myDatabase"
}
```

In Grails, the mapping block is a Groovy [closure](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures), so you're free to replace it with any other closure object whenever you'd like. This may have crazy unpredictable Hibernate side-effects or do nothing at all, as I do not know when the mapping closure is used to configure Hibernate in the Grails app lifecycle.

Comment: That's very scary. Even if it did work you might screw up your database relationships. Also, you would at the very least have to tell  hibernate to reload the mappings, as it would likely only be done (by default) during the grails application startup.