# Change DB in controller in grails

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

I have a grails application and I use mongodb as datastore. I have configured mongodb host, port and db name details in DataSource.groovy. I have multiple databases which I want to switch based on one of the values passed as query parameter in all urls hitting my application. I'm using grails GORM for mongodb for querying the DB. How do I change the database dynamically depending on the request? I would still want to continue using same gorm API. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can make a connection to new/other database, using groovy sql

```
def createConnectionToSecondDatabase() {
            def db = [url:'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/secondDatabaseName?    autoReconnect=true&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull', user:'root', password:'root', driver:'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver']
    def sql = null
    try {
        sql = Sql.newInstance(db.url, db.user, db.password, db.driver)
       sql.eachRow( 'select * from tableName' ) { 
      println "$it.id -- ${it.firstName} --" }

} catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace()
        log.error("Exception while creating connection======>>>>>>>>>>"+e)
    }finally{
        if(sql != null){
            sql.close()
        }
```

Comment: I want to know how I can do it for mongoDB. The example you've shown is for mysql. I saw that there is some way of doing it by altering mapping of metaClass groovy property of domain class as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13462379/515068 but it doesnt seem to be working for me.

Comment: I could not find a solution for this and decided to use spring's mongotemplate instead of GORM.